# Using selectors in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get data from my HTML `body` using a selector?

`$(this).text('Welcome')` works perfectly. How can I select elements by class name or by id?

I tried `$(this).find('tag name')` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/ specifically https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: You should really spend some time researching. This is 101 level which any good jQuery tutorial will cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example with `find()`. In this case "li" is the selector that we are looking for.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="level-1">
    <li class="item-i">I</li>
    <li class="item-ii">II
      <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="item-a">A</li>
        <li class="item-b">B
          <ul class="level-3">
            <li class="item-1">1</li>
            <li class="item-2">2</li>
            <li class="item-3">3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item-c">C</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-iii">III</li>
  </ul>

  <script>
  $( "li.item-ii" ).find( "li" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
  </script>
```

Comment: Please what's the class name equivalent of .text(); method?

Answer (score 1):

To select class you need to put `.` before class name and `#` to aim selector by ID.

For example:

`$('.class-name') /// class`

or

`$('#id') /// id`

or just by HTML selector

`$('body')`, `$('li')` and so on.